# NSURL Caching issues

Tags: objective-c

I'm having an issue with a login API. First call works fine, but subsequent calls are cached. This is causing an issue since login/logout functionality is essentially broke.

I've tried many methods and I'm implementing AFNetworking library.

In `AppDelegate.m`:

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                        diskCapacity:0
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

In my Networking class:

```
 (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)createRequestOperationWithMethod:(NSString *) method andPath:    (NSString *)path andParams:(NSDictionary *)params
{
  GRAPIClient *httpClient = [GRAPIClient sharedClient];
  [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:method
                                                 path:path
                                           parameters:params];

  [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData]

  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
return operation;
```

}

I even tried to overwrite the request being generated in AFHTTPClient

In AFHTTPClient.m:

```
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:2.0];
```

My GRAPIClient implementation:

```
@interface GRAPIClient : AFHTTPClient

+ (GRAPIClient *)sharedClient;
+ (BOOL) isInternetReachable;

@end

@implementation GRAPIClient

+ (BOOL) isInternetReachable
{
    return reachable;
}

+ (GRAPIClient *)sharedClient {
    static GRAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[GRAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:kAFAppDotNetAPIBaseURLString]];
});

[_sharedClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN ||
        status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi ) {
        NSLog(@"Reachable on!");
        reachable = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachable off!");
        reachable = NO;
    }
}];

return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];    
// Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    return self;
}
@end
```

I've debugged responses from the server and tested with hard coding two NSURLRequests simultaneously to the server. One for User A and one for User B, then printed the response data for both users.

On first login, User A login returned User A credentials. User B returned User B credentials. On second login, User A returned User A credentials, User B returned User A credentials. I have no idea how to fully disable cacheing.

Comment: Are you 100% that this is cause by caching? Could it be a problem with `GRAPIClient`?

Comment: I believe this is caused by caching as GRAPIClient is a simple extension of AFHTTPClient. I've updated the code to show how GRAPIClient is being implemented

Comment: Another thing to watch out for: sessions on the server side. The URL loading system handles cookies transparently, so if your first login establishes a session (and sets a session ID cookie), the outcome of your subsequent attempts might be affected. If you aren't snooping the actual HTTP traffic with something like Charles, I'd recommend that, too.

Comment: im pretty sure there is no caching here.

Comment: @SixtenOtto We're using a restless API without any cookies that relies on Auth Tokens. However since the login doesn't have an auth token at that point to pass in, we really shouldn't be having sessions on the server side. I'll take a look at Charles though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me as suggested by SixteenOtto was a session being sent from the server and AFNetworking automatically using the cookie. I hadn't considered this before since we're using a restless API based on auth tokens, so a cookie for the session makes no sense. However, inspecting the HTTP response headers with Charles allowed me to see this.

Adding

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

To my `operation` generator solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[operation setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse*(NSURLConnection* connection, NSCachedURLResponse* cachedResponse) {
    return nil;
}];
```

And:

```
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData];
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out! Unfortunately this was a server issue (which I was hoping wasn't the case). I'm adding an answer for what happened to me specifically